# Node-Webkit Menubar Add New Item Inside createMacBuiltin List

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I'm working on making a menubar for a node-webkit mac app.
I am trying to append a "Replace" menu item to the second/root menu(Edit > undo, redo, etc).
I know how to append to the default menubar `.createMacBuiltin()` creates, but it only appends to the top of that list. I'd like to append "Replace" right after "Select All". Is there anyway to append it farther down that list?

[image]

```
// Create menu container
var Menu = new gui.Menu({
  type: 'menubar'
});

//initialize default mac menu
Menu.createMacBuiltin("Hello World");

// Get the root menu from the default mac menu
var editMenu = Menu.items[1].submenu;
var windowMenu = Menu.items[2].submenu;

// Append new item to root menu
editMenu.insert(
  new gui.MenuItem({
    type: "normal",
    label: 'Replace',
    key: "f",
    modifiers: "cmd+alt",
    click : function () {
      $("[data-action=replace]").trigger("click");
    }
  })
);
windowMenu.insert(
  new gui.MenuItem({
    type: "normal",
    label: 'Toggle Fullscreen',
    key: "F",
    modifiers: "cmd",
    click : function () {
      win.toggleFullscreen();
    }
  })
);
windowMenu.insert(
  new gui.MenuItem({
    type: "normal",
    label: 'Reload App',
    key: "r",
    modifiers: "shift+cmd",
    click : function () {
      location.reload(true);
    }
  })
);

// Append Menu to Window
win.menu = Menu;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `editMenu.insert` will add the menuitem to the top, but `editMenu.append` will add it to the bottom. ()

I haven't found a way to remove `Dictation`, or `Emoji & Symbols` but was able to solve my problem with the following.

```
// Append new item to root menu
editMenu.append(
  new gui.MenuItem({
    type: "normal",
    label: 'Replace',
    key: "f",
    modifiers: "cmd+alt",
    click : function () {
      $("[data-action=replace]").trigger("click");
    }
  })
);
```

I was able to successfully remove "About MyApp" using the following...

```
rootMenu.removeAt(1);
```